# Equivalent Storyboard function for Nib

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nswindow, nib

I'm trying to convert a project on macOS that uses Storyboards to instantiate a ViewController through a delegate, although I'm running into some difficulty trying to convert it to use a Nib instead.

Currently the storyboard version of the code uses an App Delegate which is associated with two View Controllers. When a button is clicked the front window animates and flips over revealing another (back) window. The code that instantiates the View Controller is:

```
mainWindow = [NSApplication sharedApplication].windows[0];
secondaryWindow = [[NSWindow alloc]init];
[secondaryWindow setFrame:mainWindow.frame display:false];

// the below is what I'm not sure of - how to reference nib instead of storyboard?

NSStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
NSViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"BackViewController"];
[secondaryWindow setContentViewController:vc];
```

I'm not sure the proper way to reference a nib instead of a storyboard in the example shown above. [The project I'm trying to convert is located here](https://github.com/golopupinsky/NSWindow-flip-demo). I'm really hoping someone can help, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy to do. Just make an `NSViewController` subclass (or an `NSWindowController` subclass if you want it to control a whole window) for each of the two views. For each view, override `-init` and have it call super's implementation of `-initWithNibName:bundle:` with the name of the view's nib file:

```
@implementation MyViewController

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];

    if (self == nil) {
        return nil;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Note that if you can require a sufficiently recent version of macOS (I think it's 10.11 and higher off the top of my head, but it's possible that I could be off by a version or so), you don't even have to do this much, because `NSViewController` will automatically look for a nib file with the same name as the class.

Anyway, now you should be able to instantiate a `MyViewController` and insert its view into your view hierarchy, and manipulate it the same way you'd manipulate any other view:

```
MyViewController *vc = [MyViewController new];

[someSuperview addSubview:vc.view];
```

If you want to do windows instead, you can make an `NSWindowController` subclass instead of `NSViewController`. `NSWindowController` is slightly more annoying to use, since its initializers that take nib names are all *convenience* initializers, whereas the *designated* initializer just takes an `NSWindow`. So if you're using, say, Swift, you can't do it the way I did it above with `NSViewController`. Objective-C, of course, generally lets you do whatever you want, so you actually *can* get away with just calling super's `-initWithWindowNibName:owner:`, and I won't tell anyone, wink wink, nudge nudge. However, to be stylistically correct, you probably *should* just call `-initWithWindow:` passing `nil`, and then override `windowNibName` and `owner`:

```
@implementation MyWindowController

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super initWithWindow:nil];

    if (self == nil) {
        return nil;
    }

    return self;
}

- (NSNibName)windowNibName {
    return @"MyWindowController";
}

- (id)owner {
    return self;
}
```

This should get you a window controller that you can just initialize with `+new` (or `+alloc` and `-init` if you prefer), then call its `-window` property and manipulate the window as normal.